# Some K-theory Examples

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, vector-bundles, k-theory, topological-k-theory

I have a dissertation on K-theory and I've been using some references like [Hatcher's book](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) and [Karoubi's book](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~max.karoubi/K.book/MK.book.pdf). Googling a bit deeper for further examples I found that many sites use as reference the K-theory notes of "**Chris Blair, Some K-theory examples**". When I search the pdf it seems to be blocked. I just get the Web-cache version but without Latex typing, it is not so easy to follow.

Maybe have someone a pdf version of this reference? This is the [Web-Cache version](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kpsy4u656CoJ:https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~cblair/notes/kex.pdf%20&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de)

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't have a pdf of this particular manuscript, but I strongly recommend these excellent recent course notes on K-theory https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~or257/teaching/notes/Kthy.pdf. It is the content of a master's level course in the subject, and there are some nice examples illustrating the theory along the way.

Comment: I'm actually looking for that particular .pdf of Chris Blair. But, as I've been reading so far, your course notes are also quite excellent material. I'll surely check them as well. Many thanks anyway!